# How do I get id of server removed/update collection items at client side?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I would like to run some functions whenever server modifies/deletes collection items. Through help pages I got how to handle additions as below for example

```
{{#each marker}}
    {{> drawMarker}}
{{/each}}
```

and the template for drawMarker as

```
<template name="drawMarker">
   {{draw}}
</template>
```

and the corresponding helper js file contains

```
Template.drawMarker.helpers({
draw: function(){
    //function to add marker
    }
});
```

I would like to know how to handle deletions/updates for each marker if collection is updated from server side?

Comment: Notify all the clients with a list of the deleted items?

Answer (score 2):

Simple register an [`observe` `removed` callback](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe).

> Establishes a live query that invokes callbacks when the result of the query changes. The callbacks receive the entire contents of the document that was affected, as well as its old contents, if applicable.